Powershell - format info to csv
Trying to query non-windows native program (dell racadm) info and format string into csv file with other info.  Everything works until I get to the iDracIP and it returns blank in the csv file.  I know my syntax is bad but I cannot figure out what to command use to grab the "IP Address" string and pipe it into the csv file.  I have tried select-object, get-itemproperty.
$logregion = "TEST"
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "IP FQDN - $logRegion"  



$currentdate = get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd  

 
function get_info_func {  
 

$a = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\servers.txt"  
 
$get_info_array = @()  

foreach ($i in $a){  
write-host $i  
$array = New-Object PSObject  

  
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Name From List" -Value $i
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Host Name" -Value (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -computername $i | Select-Object -expandproperty dnshostname)  
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Domain" -Value (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -computername $i | Select-Object -expandproperty Domain)  
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "IPAddress" -Value ([string](Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $i | Select-object -expandproperty IPAddress) )  
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "IpSubnet" -Value ([string](Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $i | Select-object -expandproperty IpSubnet) )  
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "DefaultIPGateway" -Value ([string](Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $i | Select-object -expandproperty DefaultIPGateway) )  
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "DNSServerSearchOrder" -Value ([string](Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $i | Select-object -expandproperty DNSServerSearchOrder) )  
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Mac Address" -Value ([string](Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $i | Select-object -expandproperty MACAddress) )  
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "OS" -Value (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $i | Select-Object -expandproperty Caption)  
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "MODEL" -Value (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -computername $i | Select-Object -expandproperty Model)  
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Serial Number" -Value (Get-WmiObject -class WIN32_systemenclosure -computername $i | Select-Object -expandproperty SerialNumber)  
  $array | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "iDrac IP" -Value ([string](Invoke-Command -scriptblock { racadm.exe getniccfg } -computername $i) | Select-Object -expandproperty "IP Address")  
  

  $get_info_array += $array  

}  



$get_info_array | Export-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\IPinfo_$($logregion)_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv" -NoTypeInformation -append  

}#end function  


 & get_info_func  


a standard "racadm getniccfg" will give:
IPv4 settings:
NIC Enabled          = 1
IPv4 Enabled         = 1
DHCP Enabled         = 0
IP Address           = 0.0.0.0
Subnet Mask          = 0.0.0.0
Gateway              = 0.0.0.0

This should work
@(racadm.exe getniccfg).Where({$_ -like "*IP Address*"}) -replace '^.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*$', '$1'

Here is a simpler clear syntax:
function Get-ServerInfo {  
 
$servers = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\servers.txt"  

$ServerInfo =
    foreach ($server in $servers) {  
        Write-Host $server

        $WComputerSystem = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $server
        $NetworkAdapterConfiguration = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $server
        $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server
        $ComputerSystem = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $server
        $systemenclosure = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_systemenclosure -ComputerName $server
        [string]$iDracIP = 
            Invoke-Command  -ComputerName $server -scriptblock {
                @(racadm.exe getniccfg).Where({$_ -like "*IP Address*"}) -replace '^.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*$', '$1'
            }


        $hash = [Ordered]@{}

        $hash.NameFromList = $server
        $hash.HostName = $ComputerSystem.dnshostname
        $hash.Domain = $ComputerSystem.Domain
        $hash.IPAddress = ([string]$NetworkAdapterConfiguration.IPAddress).Trim()
        $hash.IpSubnet = ([string]$NetworkAdapterConfiguration.IpSubnet).Trim()
        $hash.DefaultIPGateway = ([string]$NetworkAdapterConfiguration.DefaultIPGateway).Trim()  
        $hash.DNSServerSearchOrder = ([string]$NetworkAdapterConfiguration.DNSServerSearchOrder).Trim()  
        $hash.MacAddress= ([string]$NetworkAdapterConfiguration.MACAddress).Trim()  
        $hash.OS = $OperatingSystem.Caption 
        $hash.MODEL = $ComputerSystem.Model 
        $hash.SerialNumber = $systemenclosure.SerialNumber 
        $hash.iDracIP = $iDracIP

        [PSCustomObject]$hash
    }

    $ServerInfo | Export-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\IPinfo_$($logregion)_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv" -NoTypeInformation -append  

}

Get-ServerInfo  


It did, thank you very much!
I followed everything you did except this part:
-replace '^.?(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+).$', '$1'
Can you explain that a bit more and how you arrived at it?  Or could you point me to documentation for that part?

@Von Does this part: -replace '^.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*$', '$1'  not work? What is his output ?

I believe it works just fine, I just dont understand it, lol.  The output the script gives for idrac IP is:  0.0.0.0 IP Address 1    =::IP Address 2  =::IP Address3 and so on all the way to 15 in that format then 192.168.0.120 Static IP Address   =::   It is giving the right IPs as I know the server I tested it on doesnt have a IP set up yet.

IPv4 settings:
NIC Enabled          = 1
IPv4 Enabled         = 1
DHCP Enabled         = 0
IP Address           = 0.0.0.0
Subnet Mask          = 0.0.0.0
Gateway              = 0.0.0.0
IPv6 settings:
IPv6 Enabled               = 0
DHCP6 Enabled              = 1
IP Address 1               = ::
Gateway                    = ::
Link Local Address         = ::
IP Address 2               = ::
IP Address 3               = ::
IP Address 4               = ::
IP Address 5               = ::
IP Address 6               = ::
IP Address 7               = ::
IP Address 8               = ::

IP Address 9               = ::
IP Address 10              = ::
IP Address 11              = ::
IP Address 12              = ::
IP Address 13              = ::
IP Address 14              = ::
IP Address 15              = ::
LOM Status:
NIC Selection   = dedicated
Link Detected   = Yes
Speed           = 1Gb/s
Duplex Mode     = Full Duplex
Active NIC      = Dedicated
Static IPv4 settings:
Static IP Address    = 0.0.0.0
Static Subnet Mask   = 0.0.0.0
Static Gateway       = 0.0.0.0

the above is what you get when you type racadm getniccfg by itself as an example out put

@Von See Replacement with regular expressions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1#replacement-operator
